# Como filtrar la versión máxima SQL

Tags: sql, select

tengo el siguiente resultado de una query SQL:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría, poder quedarme con la versión máxima para cada UFI.

He intentado hacer max(VERSION) pero me pide agrupar por el resto de columnas, y aparecen la versión maxima siempre y cuando coincidan todos los valores de las columnas, y no es lo que necesito.

Por ejm. Debería quedarme con:

ALZ1 NUCLEAR 90 200 68,72 68

ALZ2 NUCLEAR 35 100 68,72 39

¿Me podéis ayudar?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Cuando haces un `max()` tienes que utilizar el `group by`. En el caso que pides sería algo como `... max(VERSION) from ... group by UFI` ya que quieres sacar el máximo de agrupando por el nombre

Comment: El problema es que me obliga a hacer el group by con todas las columnas, no me deja solo agrupar por una de ellas.

Comment: Tendrás que hacer un group by por cada campo que quieras mostrar

Comment: Haces un group by por ufi, y traes solo ufi y max(version). Luego, eso lo usas como condicion de join, para traerte el resto de los datos...

Comment: Podrías ponerme un ejemplo sql? Muchas gracias